# "There's no point" + gerund vs "there's no point in" + gerund

Tags: phrase-usage

I've noticed that both are [used](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/There%27s+no+point) though "point in" is seemingly far more prevalent. Is there any difference or it's down to one's preferences?

E.g.

There's no point in talking to you.

vs.

There's no point talking to you.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the form without "in" is arrived at by analogy with (and in prescriptive grammar is a mistake for) "it's no use + [gerund]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both forms have the same meaning, but the true form comprises "in".

[Forum](https://forum.english.best/t/theres-no-point-doing-v-s-theres-no-point-in-doing/11109)

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/point_1?q=point))
>
> **purpose**
> ​>
> [uncountable, singular] the purpose or aim of something
>
> • What's the point of all this violence?
> • ‘Why don't you try again?’ ‘What's the point?’
> • The point of the lesson is to compare the two countries.
> • point of doing something I don't see the point of doing it all again.
> • point in doing something There's no point in getting angry.

The second form is seen to have started acquiring a certain currency after the first one.

[image]

The shortened form is used more in BrE than in AmE.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both are used without much thought and convey the same message – little consideration is ever given to the “in” or its function.

If you want to be pedantic, then the “in” locates “much point” to *within the action of talking to you* and also gives a “during the process of talking” nuance. (It strikes me as a possibility that the "in" form has more use if an alternative to talking is then offered.)

**There's no point in talking to you.** - *within/during the action of my talking to you there is no point*.

Without the “in”  **“There's no point talking to you”** equates “to the action of talking to you exists without a point”.
There's no point talking to you. This is more an observation of the whole situation -> Talking to you has no point/is pointless.